# How to manage focus on multiple inputs in grandchild component in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a situation where I have to give user the ability to edit a list and if they decide to discard the edit I show a modal which is in the grandparent.
In the modal if they decide to change their mind and hit "No", the modal closes and the focus should shift to the input field for the item they were editing. I cannot get the focus to go back on the input field for the item they were editing.
After reading a few posts I believe I need to somehow have an array of refs but I have not succeeded in getting it to work.
I have put together a quick sample here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/multipl-input-refs-2v1u1q

It does not have a dialog but you can see the same issue.
Can someone please provide some input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed in the question: this has nothing to do with a modal dialog — it is entirely about keeping track of which input last had focus, then restoring that focus at a later time (e.g. after closing the modal). This can be accomplished with a single ref.

> Be sure to read the React documentation section [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

You can pass the same ref to every input, but only selectively update the element ref in response to the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event for each input element.

Then, when you want to restore focus to the last-focused element, simply call its [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method via the ref.

Below a reproducible example. Type in one of the inputs, then click outside the input to remove focus from the element. Then click the "Restore focus" button to restore focus to that input. You can adapt these techniques to the details of your application.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=3#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-rZAU4XE0WuDxJDWu0negcStYsZxpMZrnJDs7rGCxD4NxIdAUCbSxWmzKSx10C6qT6APz2x1NslwClUmnMkZIYAw6MslkIA0tKEcDAcGwcPQcTEqkAYMB3YBIft3Eava4fOAAaxQqnNl7cjuM5odpeMTCjPw-Aa+prvSeg6DA5yGuI-KiOQj7mu2kHcN2MQMDspAdtwA4ECMgjgTAkHiKuLJ4UuK4xvs8gApQtB0C6XgpMQEAQDAdwCO0wIqpqQIuAAQqopRIESrCsSSACEPwqu6qBQLS9LBKE4SRCgJH0mmGZRqCeGKWEMARKg0axkAA)

```html
<style>body { font-family: sans-serif; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.21.2/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset("tsx", {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets["typescript"], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

import type {MutableRefObject, ReactElement} from "react";

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const {StrictMode, useRef, useState} = React;

type TextInputProps = {
  focusRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>;
};

function TextInput (props: TextInputProps): ReactElement {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={ev => setValue(ev.target.value)}
      onFocus={ev => props.focusRef.current = ev.currentTarget}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}

function App (): ReactElement {
  const focusRef = useRef<HTMLElement>();
  const restoreFocus = () => focusRef.current?.focus();

  return (
    <div>
      {
        ["a", "b"].map(id => (<TextInput key={id} focusRef={focusRef} />))
      }
      <button onClick={restoreFocus}>Restore focus</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The structure you have is a little different than mine. I'm going to see how I can apply this to my case. Will let you know if it works for me. Thanks again

Comment: I had to do some more work to get it to work in my project, Had to use useEffect and then also tie it to a new state variable but your idea really helped me out, How you suggested to save the ref onFocus. So I'm accepting your answer. Thanks.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75597905/how-to-manage-focus-on-multiple-inputs-in-grandchild-component-in-react-typescri/75601715?noredirect=1#comment133397109_75601715) Glad it worked out for you!